# CRTP refer to typedef in derived class from base class

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have following code:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    typedef typename T::Type MyType;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<B<T>>
{
    typedef T Type;
};
```

When I try to instantiate B, I get following error message using MSVS 2015:

```
'Type': is not a member of 'B<int>'
```

Is this code valid C++ or is MSVS right?

Comment: Both CLang and gcc concur with MSVC here. However, I can't understand why.

Comment: Is there any work-around in MSVC?

Comment: I know this question has been asked before, but for some reason I cannot find a dupe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is at this point

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    typedef typename T::Type MyType;
                     ^^^
};
```

`T` needs to be a complete type. But in your case, when `A<T>` is instantiated here:

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A<B<T>>
                 ^^^^^^^
```

`B<T>` is not yet a complete type! So this cannot work unfortunately.

The simple solution is just to pass in `Type` separately:

```
template <typename T, typename Type>
class A
{
    typedef Type MyType;
};    

template <typename T>
class B : public A<B<T>, T>
{

};
```

Comment: How is it possible that other compilers allow referring to typedef in incomplete type?

Comment: @AlexanderBily What other compilers?